# Terraform openstack provider fixed attribute length?

Tags: openstack, terraform

I have been receiving syntax errors using known working code when trying to use the openstack provider but in an environment that issues a very long Keystone token. >180 characters. With debug enabled I found error 400:

> plugin.terraform-provider-openstack_v1.2.0_x4.exe: "message": "Request attribute username must be less than or equal to 64. The server could not comply with the request because the attribute size is invalid (too large). The client is assumed to be in error."

As the token is the only string in the provider longer than 64 I assume that is the cause. Is it possible to increase this attribute limit?